# ftp command with put *.* does not send all files

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, ftp

I am trying to send three files say `pay.txt`, `product.txt`, `price.txt` via `ftp` from Linux to Windows machine. After I successfully login to Windows machine via `ftp`, the command I am putting is:

```
put *.*
```

But, only the first file is getting sent. Kindly help.

Error in log file:

(remote-directory) The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The error message does not seem to be related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for identifying this. The error message is related to cd $REMOTE_DIR. where I didnt send the parameter value for $REMOTE_DIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `mput` to upload all files matching a mask.

And you should use `prompt` command to avoid having to confirm each file.

```
prompt
mput *.*
```

---

*Btw, on *nix, to upload all files, use `*`, not `*.*`. Contrary to Windows on *nix, `*.*` does not match files that do not have an extension.*